# Error: Field CompanySetting__c does not exist. Check spelling

Tags: formula-field

I can't figure out what's wrong with this field formula.  Everything below in quotes has been copy/pasted directly so there are no typos AFAIK.

Custom object API name = `CompanySetting__c`
Custom object field API name = `Title__c`
Custom field formula on Lead object:
Location (Text) = `CompanySetting__c.Title__c`

> "Error: Field `CompanySetting__c` does not exist. Check spelling."

I have also tried unsuccessfully using "CompanySetting__r.Title__c"

On a different object the following field formula works as expected: `Account.Location_Title__c`

But that might be due to the fact that the object is not a custom object even though the field is a custom field.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See also [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_creating_cross_object_simple.htm&type=5)

Comment: What is the API name of the lookup field on the Lead object? `CompanySetting__r.Title__c` should work *if* the lookup field's API name is `CompanySetting__c`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand "lookup field on the Lead object" - did you mean custom object?  Also don't understand "lookup fields API name is CompanySetting__c" when that is the custom object's API name.

Comment: You must have a field connecting Lead to CompanySetting__c. What is the API name of that field? If there's no relationship between the two objects, you won't be able to create a cross-object formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom object API name = CompanySetting__c
Custom object field API name = Title__c
/**************************************/
Let say the Lookupfield Api Name which references the CompanySetting__c records from Lead Object is CompanySettingLkp__c.
Then
Custom field formula on Lead object:
Location (Text) = CompanySettingLkp__r.Title__c

Salesforce maintains a relationship between Lead and Account so every Lead will be under some Account, they have reference fields defined by salesforce but in your case its custom object where salesforce didn't provide anything, you need to create Lookup field to CompanySetting__c afterwards with the name of the Lookup you can have Cross-Object Data.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried that and got the same "does not exist" error.

Comment: What is the name of you lookup file in Lead?

Comment: I am trying to create a new formula field on the Lead object with the name of "Location".  As I cannot get past the formula step, the field does not yet exist.

Comment: Before creating the formula field you need to create some reference field first, either Master-Detail/Lookup to CompanySetting__c, does it exists? Afterwards you can create cross-object formula field.

Comment: Salesforce maintains a relationship between Lead and Account so every Lead will be under some Account, they have reference fields defined by salesforce but in your case its custom object where salesforce didn't provide anything, you need to create Lookup field to COmpanySetting__c afterwards with the name of the Lookup you can have Cross-Object Data.

Comment: AHA!  That's the issue (I believe anyway).  I do not have a separate custom lookup field to CompanySetting__c.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes right. You got it. Kindly mark it as the best answer.